# MySQL Proc Call - Set Strange Behaviour

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I Have a table somewhat like this:

rnumber

number = int, cod = int

SELECT * FROM number WHERE number = 21377 and cod = 55;
returns the correct value;

So i have a proc call to insert:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `create`(IN Numb INT, IN Cod INT, IN qt INT)
BEGIN
    SET @Cont = 0;
    SET @Init = Numb;   
    WHILE @Cont < qt DO
      SET @Exist = (SELECT count(number) FROM rnumber WHERE number = @Init AND cod = Cod LIMIT 1);  
        IF @Exist = 0 THEN
             INSERT INTO (...)
        END IF;
      SET @Cont = @Cont + 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      SET @IniT = @Init + 1;
  END WHILE;  
END$$
```

CALL `create` (21377, 54, 1);

Always give me variable @Exist as 1, so no go on the if, even tho the combination of number and cod does not exists.

Can anyone point me what am i doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using select into instead of set xx = (select...).

Also having `cod = Cod` will always return true...

You also need to declare your variables...

Try this one:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `create`(IN p_Numb INT, IN p_Cod INT, IN p_qt INT)
BEGIN
declare v_Exist integer;
declare v_Init integer;
declare v_Exist integer;
    SET v_Cont = 0;
    SET v_Exist = 0;
    SET v_Init = p_Numb;   
    WHILE v_Cont < p_qt DO
      SELECT count(number) into v_Exist FROM rnumber WHERE number = v_Init AND cod = p_Cod LIMIT 1;  
        IF v_Exist = 0 THEN
             INSERT INTO (...)
        END IF;
      SET v_Cont = v_Cont +1;                    
      SET v_IniT = v_Init + 1;
  END WHILE;  
END$$
```

Comment: Thank you. It was a case sensitive problem with the 2 cod columns.